# What can I use to clean the walls in my bathroom before repainting?

Tags: bathroom, repainting

The paint in our bathroom is starting to peal and there are strange "brown spots" guessing from a shampoo or something (definitely not mold). What can I use to clean that up before repainting everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use TSP. You can get it at HD/Lowes. Follow the precautions!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're painting over drywall, and not tile or plastic or some other substrate? Use a good stain hiding primer such as KILZ, and then paint over it with a premium paint such as Benjamin Moore Aquavelvet.

KILZ will cover the stain and prevent it from showing through again.

Using a premium paint will leave a thicker, more water- and chemical- resistant finish that won't wipe off the first time you clean the bathroom.

Comment: What should I wash the walls with?